# What indexes do I need to improve mysql query performance via Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an app with db that grows rapidly - currently a number of tables are around 70k rows and rising.  My queries are run using Laravel's eloquent, so I understand some overhead there, but even running a single join in mysqlworkbench, has resulted in me having to stop the query because of how long it was taking.

The tables I'm working with:

```
posts:
id, session_id, cat_id, name, lat, long

cats:
id, session_id, name

sessions:
id, member_id, token, created_at, updated_at

members:
id, memnum, email, name, state, postcode
```

Each `id` field has its own primary key index, and my first step was to add indexes to each of the FK's, but surprisingly I haven't seen any benefit from that.

I also tried adding composite indexes, like

```
create index `sid` on posts(`session_id`, `cat_id`);
```

That also doesn't seem to help.  In order to test these performance differences, I ran a join query that would be similar to what eloquent is doing using the `EXPLAIN`:

```
explain select p.name, t.name, m.member_num from posts p, cats c, members m
left join sessions s on m.id = s.member_id
where p.created_at > date('2017-12-31');
```

Before adding the indexes and after adding them, the rows number simply does not seem to change at all from about 75k - I would expect this to decrease significantly if the indexes helped ?  Am I doing it wrong ?

As some background in case anyone thinks eloquent could be fixed, here is the request:

```
        $offers = Post::with(['session.member', 'cat'])
        ->where('created_at', '>=', $dates[0])
        ->where('created_at', '<', $dates[1])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have too many records in your database so you have to limit the number of results you get from eloquent. You can use a closure in your `with` and limit number of records that might help you.

```
 $offers = Post::with(['session.member'=> function($query){
           return $query->take(10); // Limit the number of records
 }, 'cat'])
->where('created_at', '>=', $dates[0])
->where('created_at', '<', $dates[1])
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->get();
```